# C# Using .Count with Tuple Items

Tags: c#, tuples

I am trying to compare the contents of a number of Tuples inside of a List. The code runs reasonable well, but on certain occasions, `completeList[z].Item1.Count` will come back with the wrong number. When I look in the debugger, in one example `a = completeList[z].Item1.Count` might return 18 when the count is 9. So this causes it to go out of range.

`completeList.Count` returns correctly, as does `completeList[z].Item1[b]`, so I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong with `completeList[z].Item1.Count`.

Thanks for any insights!

```
int x = completeList.Count;
int y = 0;
while (y < x)
{
 for (int z = 0; z < x; z++)
 {
  if (y != z && completeList[y].Item6.Equals(completeList[z].Item6))
  {
   int a = completeList[z].Item1.Count;
   a = a -1;
   for (int b = 0; b < a; b++)
   {
    if (completeList[y].Item1.Contains(completeList[z].Item1[b]))
    {
     completeList[z].Item1.RemoveAt(b);
     completeList[z].Item2.RemoveAt(b);
     completeList[z].Item3.RemoveAt(b);
     completeList[z].Item4.RemoveAt(b);
     completeList[z].Item5.RemoveAt(b);
    }
   }
  }
 }
 y++;
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `completeList`?

Comment: List<Tuple<List<string>, List<string>, List<string>, List<string>, List<string>, string>>

Comment: Are you sure all lists of your tuple have the same length?

Comment: You might consider using a class rather than a Tuple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're removing items from the list.  This is changing the count, and also moving around the indexes of the existing items.  The count is correct at the start of the loop, but by the time you've actually removed an item, the count is no longer valid.

The most effective solution is to not iterate the list while removing items at all; instead rely on the list's `RemoveAll` method to remove all of the items that match your list of items to remove.  While it's *possible* for you to manage the indexes properly to remove while iterating, you should avoid this complexity.

Comment: That makes sense. Let me see what I can do about this.

Comment: I added `a--` and `b--` after my `RemoveAt()` and it worked perfectly. Completely overlooked the fact that my count would be shifting. Thanks for the quick help!

Comment: @thatkindofmatt I would discourage you from doing that, for reasons I explained in my answer.  You create programs that become much harder to reason about than they really ought to be, greatly increasing your potential for bugs, making updates to the code harder, and making it harder for people reading the code again to understand it.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions - I'm parsing through a lot of data from a variety of sources. Each Tuple represents a source w/ a unique data set of varying lengths. I'm removing duplicates btwn Tuples.

The part that I do think could be optimized is each List (inside the Tuple) is a different sort of data, but each List is the same length, and the data in each position is correlated (thus why I remove each position at `b`). If there is a duplicate in Item1, then I need to remove that position from all Items in that Tuple. If I could structure this better it may make the search and removal easier?

Comment: completeList =  List<Tuple<List<string>, List<string>, List<string>, List<string>, List<string>, string>>

Comment: @thatkindofmatt The solution there is to not keep 5 lists in which the item at each index corresponds to one value of an item.  Instead create a class with 5 properties, and create a list of those classes.  That will be much, *much* easier to work with.

Comment: That's fair. I appreciate all the input